# WPF. Скрыть элементы при пустом TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть редактируемый TextBox, у которого во время выполнения мы можем стереть то что он выводит. Как сделать так, что бы при пустом его значении скрыть некоторые элементы?

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBox1}"
                         Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Пробовал сделать через триггеры, но это работает только при загрузке, если же во время выполнения стереть из TextBox значение то ничего не произойдет

Comment: Сравнивайте не с `null`, а с пустой строкой

Comment: @Андрей Да тут даже не в этом дело видимо(хотя здесь тоже есть косяк). Видимо это поле никак не обновляется, т.е оно один раз считалось и все, а если я его меняю-то он никак не реагирует

Comment: @MrStacky не может быть

Answer (score 2):

Все будет работать если сравнивать не с `{x:Null}` а с пустой строкой как вам уже написали в комментариях.

Проверить то не сложно

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="Пример" />
<TextBlock Text="Какой-то текст">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBox1}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

гифка в подтверждение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]